# Moving an div from the top left corner to bottom right using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move a div from top left corner to bottom right corner using only CSS (this is required for my assignment). Also, I need to see the transition happening (the div sliding to the bottom). I tried using `transform:translate()` but i can't get my div to go to the bottom corner! Here is what I've done until now: http://codepen.io/ascii-hero/pen/JXEXVB

Comment: Can you use javascript or no?

Comment: I cannot use javascript.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney for a transform such as this, there shouldn't be need for javascript.

Comment: Agreed @jbutler483 - I haven't played much with `transform: translate`  - great answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tldr;

**Solution 1: Using Left/Right/Top/Bottom positioning**

In order for your div to move, you will need to set a parent element to `relative`, and the div to `absolute` positioning. Note, since the `html` element is the 'top most' element of the html tree, it is automatically assumed this `relative` position.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
html:hover div {
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Solution 2: Transforms**

Using transforms is great, as you can *also add transitions for a smooth effect*. Just note you'll need to add just a slight alteration to solution 1.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
html:hover div {
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

*Explanation of Solution 2*

To allow for transforms, the DOM needs to know the start point, the end point, and the duration **explicitly**. So hence, the start is set to

```
top:0; left:0;
```

To represent the top and left vales.

The 'duration' can be set using the `transition` property. Here I have set this to 0.4s(econds), but this can be altered to any suitable value.

Lastly, and most crucially, you need to set a definitive end point to your transform. Here you will notice the

```
top:100%;left:100%;
```

However, as I am sure you are aware in doing that it will put the very top left corner at this position, (100%,100%) so to speak. It is hence the reason for the inclusion for the `translate` to 'move the box back onto the screen'. The translate property takes two values, the X and Y disposition. By using a % as the unit, it will move a % of the size of either the width or height of the box, depending on the axis you are moving it. In other words, using

```
transform:translate(-100%, -100%);
```

will move the box 100% (of itself) to the left, and 100% (of its height) up, hence it can be seen in the bottom right of the page.

Comment: The only problem is that I actually need to see the transition happening (the div sliding to the bottom right corner). I was not explicit enough, I will edit the question.

Comment: @Dana Solution 2 does this for you.

Comment: This was what I needed, easy to understand too! Thank you

Comment: not a problem @Dana, I have added an explanation to hopefully clarify

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#block:hover {
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
    -webkit-transition-property: left, top, background, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s, 2s, 1s, 1s;
    transform:translate(-100%, -100%);
  }
```

I'm on mobile so I hav t tested it but it /should/ work

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. The div just moves out of sight.

Comment: Changed the vw|vh values to % hopefully that helps

Answer (score -1):

So you want to move the div to bottom right corner. In your code you are doing

```
#block {
 background: cornflowerblue;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

so instead of top to be 0, you want bottom to be 0, and instead of left you want right.

Comment: Please read the question `I am trying to move a div from top left corner to bottom right corner`